# shell get string

Tags: bash, shell

I have some lines have same structure like

```
1000    AS34_59329    RICwdsRSYHSD11-2-IPAAPEK-93     /ifshk5/BC_IP/PROJECT/T1
1073/T11073_RICekkR/Fq/AS34_59329/111220_I631_FCC0E5EACXX_L4_RICwdsRSYHSD11-2-IP
AAPEK-93_1.fq.gz        /ifshk5/BC_IP/PROJECT/T11073/T11073_RICekkR/Fq/AS34_5932
9/111220_I631_FCC0E5EACXX_L4_RICwdsRSYHSD11-2-IPAAPEK-93_2.fq.gz        /ifshk5/
BC_IP/PROJECT/T11073/T11073_RICekkR/Fq/AS34_59329/clean_111220_I631_FCC0E5EACXX_
L4_RICwdsRSYHSD11-2-IPAAPEK-93_1.fq.gz.total.info       11.824  0.981393
43.8283 95.7401 OK
```

And I want to get the Bold part to check whether in `/home/jesse/` has this folder, if not create mkdir `/home/jesse/AS34_59329`

I use this code

```
  ! /bin/bash
  myPath="/home/jesse/"
  while read myline
  do
     dirname= echo "$myline" | awk -F ' ' '{print $2}'
     echo $dirname
     myPath= $myPath$dirname
     echo $myPath
     mkdir -p "$myPath"

  done < T11073_all_3254.fq.list
```

But it can't mkdir and show the path name, it shows

```
 -bash: /home/jesse/: is a directory
 /home/jesse/
 AS39_59324
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`read` can read each field into a separate variable, and `mkdir -p` will create a dir only if it doesn't exist:

```
path="/home/jesse"
while read _ dir _ 
do 
    mkdir -p "$path/$dir"
done < T11073_all_3254.fq.list
```

Comment: Did you change your code to incorporate this, or did you copy-paste this suggestion?

Comment: i found the reason is in awk, it can't get the AS34_59329

Comment: it can work, can you tell me why the $dir can get the dir information like AS34_59329

Comment: `read a b c <<< "one two three four five"` will make `a=one`, `b=two`, `c="three four five"`. `_` is just a dummy variable name.

Answer (score 0):

`for` will iterate over each whitespace separated token. Try this instead.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
# Invoke with first arg as file containing the lines
#     foo.sh <input_filename>

for i in `cat $1 | cut -d " " -f2`
do 
    if [ -d /home/jesse/$i ]
    then
        echo "Directory /home/jesse/$i exists"
    else
        mkdir /home/jesse/$i;
        echo "Directory /home/jesse/$i created"
    fi
done
```

Comment: What did you try and what result did you get?